# Any way to bypass the 1MB size restriction on synonyms.txt resource in DataStax Solr?

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to use the synonyms.txt from WordNet, which is about 1.5MB. When I try to upload it with curl, it responds that resource files may not exceed 1MB in size. I confirmed that if I truncate the file to under 1MB, it uploads fine and is used as expected (albeit with only a subset of the synonym list).

Is there an alternative way to upload this resource, or maybe a directory where it may be copied instead?

Comment: The synonyms attribute may contain multiple files separated by a comma.  This will enable going beyond the 1 MB limit.

Comment: @RockBrain That worked, thanks! Please add it as an answer so I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but right now that is the limit for the size of Solr resource files in DSE.

But I will pass that on as a suggested improvement. I mean, some of these limits are somewhat arbitrary and could be increased a bit without degrading the overall product performance.

Comment: Thanks Jack! I'd upvote your answer, but I don't have enough rep.